# how to get password field value using javascript? please i help out i am stucked on it since morning

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using `document.getElementById("password").value` to recieve the password type input field.

please help out!

the form also has an `action="authenticate_signup.php"`

it shows as if the password field value is not retrieved.

Comment: It [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Qun7G/1/), the problem is not in the code you've show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your element id is defined properly.

It should work as expected, there is no security restriction.
You can even switch between input types like:
    document.getElementById("password").type = 'textbox';

Comment: While you can switch between types in theory, in practise this will break in some versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var password = document.getElementById('password');

if(password.value==""){
    alert('No password entered!');
}
```

It's this simple. This should work. You probably have some other javascript error that is preventing this code to execute. Try using console in firefox or chrome to see that error.